# ASP.NET GroupBox look like using fieldset with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using modal popup with a table inside . I want to group some employee information using fieldset, but the problem fieldset and table row break into 2 parts.

```
<fieldset class="box-border">
    <legend class="box-border">Basic information</legend>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:label id="plEmpCode" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="Employee ID (*)"></asp:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpCode" CssClass="textnumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valEmpCode" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmpCode" ErrorMessage="Enter Employee ID" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" runat="server" CssClass="customCalloutStyle" TargetControlID="valEmpCode"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:label id="plEnrollNumber" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="Enroll Number (*)"></asp:label>
        </td>
    ..........
</fieldset>
```

css in bootstrap:

```
fieldset.box-border 
{
    border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
            box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}

legend.box-border {
    width:auto; /* Or auto */
    padding:0 10px; /* To give a bit of padding on the left and right */
    border-bottom:none;

    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    text-align: left !important;

}
```

and this is result:
[image]

Inspect HTML Element result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and changing the structure of `HTML` to:

```
...
<tr>
  <td>
    <fieldset class="box-border">
      <legend class="box-border">Basic information</legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:label id="plEmpCode" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="Employee ID (*)"></asp:label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpCode" CssClass="textnumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valEmpCode" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmpCode" ErrorMessage="Enter Employee ID" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" runat="server" CssClass="customCalloutStyle" TargetControlID="valEmpCode"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:label id="plEnrollNumber" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="Enroll Number (*)"></asp:label>
          </td>
          ..........
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>
...
```

can resolve...